# Why would 'clearTimeout' not work in this scenario?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, timeout

I'm having an issue stopping the 'gameTimer' timer from running with 'clearTimeout()' in my code. I have simplified part of my code here to only contain the necessary details.

```
//This runs when someone connects to my website
io.on('connection', function (socket) {

    let gameTimer;

    //Runs the in-game timer
    function questionCountdown() {
        
        gameTimer = setTimeout(function () {
            //Reveal if the players' answers are right or wrong
            revealAnswer(answeredPlayers, playerData[socket.id].room);

            //Start the countdown for the next question
            countToNextQuestion(playerData[socket.id].room);
        }, 21000)
    }


    //Starts the game
    socket.on('Request Game Start', async function (room) {
        questionCountdown();
    })

    //Runs when a player has answered(ignore the function arguments)
    socket.on('Answered Question', function () {

        //If all users in the room have answered...
        if (answeredPlayers.get(playerData[socket.id].room) == (roomMap.get(playerData[socket.id].room)).length) {

            //Stop the count[THE MAIN ISSUE]
            clearTimeout(gameTimer);

            //Reveal if the players' answers are right or wrong
            revealAnswer(answeredPlayers, playerData[socket.id].room);

            //Start the countdown for the next question
            countToNextQuestion(playerData[socket.id].room);

        }
    })

})
```

Is there any reason why the "clearTimeout()" used in `socket.on('Answered Question', function () {`would not work?

Comment: What issue are you having?  Please describe in more detail exactly what events occur, what you observe happening and what you expect or want to happen.

Comment: Also, please correct the indentation of your code so we can more easily see what code is in what event handlers.

Comment: Are you sure that your if condition is being met sometimes? For example, put a console.log in to make sure you are entering that code. And is it being met when the timer has already been cleared?

Comment: @jfriend00 I've indented a bit better. When someone answers the question, i want the timer to stop. But at the moment it is not stopping,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible reasons that the `clearTimeout()` doesn't stop a previously started `gameTimer`:

1. The `socket.on('Answered Question', ...)` event isn't happening when you think it is.  Either it's never happening or it's happening too soon.
2. The condition `if (answeredPlayers.get(playerData[socket.id].room) == (roomMap.get(playerData[socket.id].room)).length)` isn't being met or throws and thus you never get to the `clearTimeout()`.
3. You start more than one `gameTimer` for a given user before stopping one, thus the second overwrites the timer from the first and you then never stop the first one.
4. Your user leaves the web page or hits refresh and since you don't show listening for the `disconnect` event, you leave a `gameTimer` running that can never get stopped.  FYI, this should be addressed whether it's the cause of the current problem you're looking at or not.
5. Since each socket.io connection has their own `gameTimer`, you are just confused about whether it is or isn't getting stopped and perhaps one `gameTimer` is getting stopped and you're just being fooled by the fact that there are others also running that belong to different connections.

FYI, you can figure out if any of these are the cause with appropriate `console.log()` statements and then studying the logs.  These timing-sensitive, event driven problems are usually solved with detailed logging and then studying the logs to see exactly what did and didn't happen in your code and in what order.

Comment: Wow, very in-depth. Thank you very much. I will review my code, taking into account all you have said.

Answer (score 0):

In your code since the setting of the Timeout is triggered by an event, it might occur that `clearTimeout` get's called without `gameTime` being set. Also `clearTimeout` is being triggered by an event and if that event doesn't fire the timeout won't be cleared.

The problem might lie in the source of your events. Where or when do they get triggered?

You might also test your `if` statement. Put a `console.log` before calling `clearTimeout` and see if it get's run when you want it to.

Comment: I know```if (answeredPlayers.get(playerData[socket.id].room) ==(roomMap.get(playerData[socket.id].room)).length) {``` works because ```revealAnswer()``` and ```countToNextQuestion()```  both work. You might be right on the events thing. I will have to check again